# Failed to start jboss.deployment.unit."war".POST_MODULE

Tags: maven-3, netbeans-8, jboss-eap-6

I created a Maven Project using the RESTful Web Service from Database in NetBeans by following this tutorial:

http://jaxenter.com/from-database-to-restful-web-service-to-html5-in-10-minutes-105524.html and http://jaxenter.com/from-database-to-restful-web-service-to-html5-in-five-minutes-107078.html

When I tried to run this in Glassfish 4.1 as a packaged war file, my RESTful Web Service works fine.

However, I want to use JBoss EAP 6.1 instead of Glassfish, however it ran into many problems. Here's the message from JBoss when I run `standalone.sh`:

```
18:16:33,320 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC0000
01: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."mhc-maven-jboss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.
war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployme
nt.unit."mhc-maven-jboss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to pr
ocess phase POST_MODULE of deployment "mhc-maven-jboss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(Deplo
ymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.
Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(Se
rviceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-
1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceCont
rollerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceRefProcessor.getPersistenceUnit
BindingSource(PersistenceRefProcessor.java:203)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceRefProcessor.getPersistenceUnit
Refs(PersistenceRefProcessor.java:124)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceRefProcessor.processDescriptorE
ntries(PersistenceRefProcessor.java:75)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.AbstractDeploymentDescriptorBindi
ngsProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentDescriptorBindingsProcessor.java:95)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(Deplo
ymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.
Final-redhat-8]
        ... 5 more

18:16:33,370 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS0
18559: Deployed "mhc-maven-jboss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "mhc-maven-jb
oss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
18:16:33,372 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774
: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit
."mhc-maven-jboss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartExce
ption in service jboss.deployment.unit."mhc-maven-jboss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_M
ODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "mhc-maven-
jboss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
```

My pom.xml (some parts of it Auto-generated by NetBeans) is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.mhc</groupId>
  <artifactId>mhc-maven-jboss</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>mhc-maven-jboss</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies> 

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>  
          <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>  
              <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
              <version>7.5.Final</version>  
        </plugin>  
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

My persistence.xml is (which is almost the same with the one I created using Glassfish server):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="mhcDS" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mhcDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following points checked:

- Create a JNDI Datasource Entry in the JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml (examples are given within) or via the Admin Page
- Watch the Server Logs on Startup (/standalone/logs/server.log). You should see the following line:`[org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/mhcDS]`
- Even though it is not required by the JPA Spec, add the desired Provider in the persistence.xml (Default for JBoss EAP 6 is Hibernate, so add the following Line as the first child under the persistence-unit Element: `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` (Further Information can be found here: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ch01s02s01.html)

Comment: The Maven dependency "javaee-web-api" v 6.0 has EntityManager class in its jar and I think that's where I am having problem. How can I make my persistence imports to come from "hibernate-entitymanager" artifact instead of "javaee-web-api"?

Comment: The javaee-web-API just defines the interface, the definition, the contract. You are developing against these interfaces an when deploying your code, the implementation wich implements the interfaces defined in the API will execute the actual tasks. In this case JBoss provides Hibernate as an implementation to the JPA Specification wich will then be used. You do not have to use hibernate imports if you are not using any special Hibernate features, hibernate will automatically be used when you use the J2E API within JBoss. (Compared to Glassfish wich uses EclipseLink)

Comment: I was able to get to the point, `[org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/mhcDS]` but at the end that POST_MODULE still comes up.